# Convert csv file to json with no quotes around float values

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I have some csv files that I need to convert to json. Some of the float values in the csv are numeric strings (to maintain trailing zeros). When converting to json, all keys and values are wrapped in double quotes. I need the numeric string float values to not have quotes, but maintain the trailing zeros.

Here is a sample of the input csv file:

```
ACCOUNTNAMEDENORM,DELINQUENCYSTATUS,RETIRED,INVOICEDAYOFWEEK,ID,BEANVERSION,ACCOUNTTYPE,ORGANIZATIONTYPEDENORM,HIDDENTACCOUNTCONTAINERID,NEWPOLICYPAYMENTDISTRIBUTABLE,ACCOUNTNUMBER,PAYMENTMETHOD,INVOICEDELIVERYTYPE,DISTRIBUTIONLIMITTYPE,CLOSEDATE,FIRSTTWICEPERMTHINVOICEDOM,HELDFORINVOICESENDING,FEINDENORM,COLLECTING,ACCOUNTNUMBERDENORM,CHARGEHELD,PUBLICID
John Smith,2.0000000000,0.0000000000,5.0000000000,1234567.0000000000,69.0000000000,1.0000000000,,4321987.0000000000,1,000-000-000-00,10012.0000000000,10002.0000000000,3.0000000000,,1.0000000000,0,,0,000-000-000-00,0,bc:1234346
```

The json output I am getting is:

```json
{"ACCOUNTNAMEDENORM":"John Smith","DELINQUENCYSTATUS":"2.0000000000","RETIRED":"0.0000000000","INVOICEDAYOFWEEK":"5.0000000000","ID":"1234567.0000000000","BEANVERSION":"69.0000000000","ACCOUNTTYPE":"1.0000000000","ORGANIZATIONTYPEDENORM":null,"HIDDENTACCOUNTCONTAINERID":"4321987.0000000000","NEWPOLICYPAYMENTDISTRIBUTABLE":"1","ACCOUNTNUMBER":"000-000-000-00","PAYMENTMETHOD":"12345.0000000000","INVOICEDELIVERYTYPE":"98765.0000000000","DISTRIBUTIONLIMITTYPE":"3.0000000000","CLOSEDATE":null,"FIRSTTWICEPERMTHINVOICEDOM":"1.0000000000","HELDFORINVOICESENDING":"0","FEINDENORM":null,"COLLECTING":"0","ACCOUNTNUMBERDENORM":"000-000-000-00","CHARGEHELD":"0","PUBLICID":"xx:1234346"}
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('output2.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('output2.json', 'w')

readHeaders = csv.reader(csvfile)
fieldnames = next(readHeaders)

reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)

for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile, separators=(',', ':'))
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

I would like the output to have no quotes around float values, similar to the following:

```
{"ACCOUNTNAMEDENORM":"John Smith","DELINQUENCYSTATUS":2.0000000000,"RETIRED":0.0000000000,"INVOICEDAYOFWEEK":5.0000000000,"ID":1234567.0000000000,"BEANVERSION":69.0000000000,"ACCOUNTTYPE":1.0000000000,"ORGANIZATIONTYPEDENORM":null,"HIDDENTACCOUNTCONTAINERID":4321987.0000000000,"NEWPOLICYPAYMENTDISTRIBUTABLE":"1","ACCOUNTNUMBER":"000-000-000-00","PAYMENTMETHOD":12345.0000000000,"INVOICEDELIVERYTYPE":98765.0000000000,"DISTRIBUTIONLIMITTYPE":3.0000000000,"CLOSEDATE":null,"FIRSTTWICEPERMTHINVOICEDOM":1.0000000000,"HELDFORINVOICESENDING":"0","FEINDENORM":null,"COLLECTING":"0","ACCOUNTNUMBERDENORM":"000-000-000-00","CHARGEHELD":"0","PUBLICID":"xx:1234346"}
```

Comment: If you don’t want quotes, you have to covert them to float, but then the trailing zeros will be gone. If that what you want?

Comment: I need to keep the trailing zeros

Comment: DaveC: *Why* exactly do you need to keep the trailing zeros? Getting `json.dump()` to do something like that it fairly involved—although it can be done—but I'd like to know the reason it's important to you.

Comment: The trailing zeros are from an initial json file that I convert to csv and mask all sensitive fields and then convert back to json. The masking tool that we use does not support json currently which is why I have to convert. The system that consumes the json data needs the zeros for some reason. I am able to convert the json to csv just fine, but converting back to json puts quotes around all values. I need the converted json file to have the same formatting as the initial pre-converted json file (but with masked data). Hopefully this helps explain why I am trying to format this way.

Comment: Are you comparing them with the 'original' values? The numerical value would stay the same, and if you compare them by a numerical means they are still the same number, just not the same string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, from your comments, that I understand your question better, here's a completely different answer. Note that it doesn't use the `json` module and just does the processing needed "manually". Although it probably could be done using the module, getting it to format the Python data types it recognizes by default differently can be fairly involved — I know from experience — as compared to the relatively simple logic used below anyway.

Anther note: Like your code, this converts each row of the csv file into a valid JSON object and writes each one to a file on a separate line. However the contents of the resulting file technically won't be valid JSON because all of these individual objects need to be be comma-separated and enclosed in `[` `]` brackets (i.e. thereby becoming a valid JSON "Array" Object).

```
import csv

with open('output2.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile, \
     open('output2.json', 'w') as jsonfile:

    for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile):
        newfmt = []
        for field, value in row.items():
            field = '"{}"'.format(field)
            try:
                float(value)
            except ValueError:
                value = 'null' if value == '' else '"{}"'.format(value)
            else:
                # Avoid changing integer values to float.
                try:
                    int(value)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
                else:
                    value = '"{}"'.format(value)

            newfmt.append((field, value))

        json_repr = '{' + ','.join(':'.join(pair) for pair in newfmt) + '}'
        jsonfile.write(json_repr + '\n')
```

This is the JSON written to the file:

```
{"ACCOUNTNAMEDENORM":"John Smith","DELINQUENCYSTATUS":2.0000000000,"RETIRED":0.0000000000,"INVOICEDAYOFWEEK":5.0000000000,"ID":1234567.0000000000,"BEANVERSION":69.0000000000,"ACCOUNTTYPE":1.0000000000,"ORGANIZATIONTYPEDENORM":null,"HIDDENTACCOUNTCONTAINERID":4321987.0000000000,"NEWPOLICYPAYMENTDISTRIBUTABLE":"1","ACCOUNTNUMBER":"000-000-000-00","PAYMENTMETHOD":12345.0000000000,"INVOICEDELIVERYTYPE":98765.0000000000,"DISTRIBUTIONLIMITTYPE":3.0000000000,"CLOSEDATE":null,"FIRSTTWICEPERMTHINVOICEDOM":1.0000000000,"HELDFORINVOICESENDING":"0","FEINDENORM":null,"COLLECTING":"0","ACCOUNTNUMBERDENORM":"000-000-000-00","CHARGEHELD":"0","PUBLICID":"bc:1234346"}
```

Shown again below with added whitespace:

```
{"ACCOUNTNAMEDENORM": "John Smith",
 "DELINQUENCYSTATUS": 2.0000000000,
 "RETIRED": 0.0000000000,
 "INVOICEDAYOFWEEK": 5.0000000000,
 "ID": 1234567.0000000000,
 "BEANVERSION": 69.0000000000,
 "ACCOUNTTYPE": 1.0000000000,
 "ORGANIZATIONTYPEDENORM": null,
 "HIDDENTACCOUNTCONTAINERID": 4321987.0000000000,
 "NEWPOLICYPAYMENTDISTRIBUTABLE": "1",
 "ACCOUNTNUMBER": "000-000-000-00",
 "PAYMENTMETHOD": 12345.0000000000,
 "INVOICEDELIVERYTYPE": 98765.0000000000,
 "DISTRIBUTIONLIMITTYPE": 3.0000000000,
 "CLOSEDATE": null,
 "FIRSTTWICEPERMTHINVOICEDOM": 1.0000000000,
 "HELDFORINVOICESENDING": "0",
 "FEINDENORM": null,
 "COLLECTING": "0",
 "ACCOUNTNUMBERDENORM": "000-000-000-00",
 "CHARGEHELD": "0",
 "PUBLICID": "bc:1234346"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit of overkill, but with [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) it would be pretty simple:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('output2.csv')
data.to_json(''output2.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a regular expression to see if the string value looks like a float, and convert it to a float if it is.

```
import re

null = None
j = {"ACCOUNTNAMEDENORM":"John Smith","DELINQUENCYSTATUS":"2.0000000000",
     "RETIRED":"0.0000000000","INVOICEDAYOFWEEK":"5.0000000000",
     "ID":"1234567.0000000000","BEANVERSION":"69.0000000000",
     "ACCOUNTTYPE":"1.0000000000","ORGANIZATIONTYPEDENORM":null,
     "HIDDENTACCOUNTCONTAINERID":"4321987.0000000000",
     "NEWPOLICYPAYMENTDISTRIBUTABLE":"1","ACCOUNTNUMBER":"000-000-000-00",
     "PAYMENTMETHOD":"12345.0000000000","INVOICEDELIVERYTYPE":"98765.0000000000",
     "DISTRIBUTIONLIMITTYPE":"3.0000000000","CLOSEDATE":null,
     "FIRSTTWICEPERMTHINVOICEDOM":"1.0000000000","HELDFORINVOICESENDING":"0",
     "FEINDENORM":null,"COLLECTING":"0","ACCOUNTNUMBERDENORM":"000-000-000-00",
     "CHARGEHELD":"0","PUBLICID":"xx:1234346"}

for key in j:
    if j[key] is not None:
        if re.match("^\d+?\.\d+?$", j[key]):
            j[key] = float(j[key])
```

I used `null = None` here to deal with the "null"s that show up in the JSON.  But you can replace 'j' here with each CSV row you're reading, then use this to update the row before writing it back with the floats replacing the strings.

If you're OK with converting any numerical string into a float, then you can skip the regular expression (`re.match()` command) and replace it with `j[key].isnumeric()`, if it's available for your Python version.

**EDIT**: I don't think floats in Python handle the "precision" in a way you might think.  It may look like `2.0000000000` is being "truncated" to `2.0`, but I think this is more of a formatting and display issue, rather than losing information.  Consider the following examples:

```
>>> float(2.0000000000)
2.0
>>> float(2.00000000001)
2.00000000001
>>> float(1.00) == float(1.000000000)
True
>>> float(3.141) == float(3.140999999)
False
>>> float(3.141) == float(3.1409999999999999)
True
>>> print('%.10f' % 3.14)
3.1400000000
```

It's possible though to get the JSON to have those zeroes, but in that case it comes down to treating the number as a string, namely a formatted one.

Comment: This works to get rid of the quotes on the numeric sting floats, but it truncates the trailing zeros.

Comment: It's not truncating per se.  I've edited my post to explain this in further detail.

Answer (score 0):

Hah, it's really interesting, I want to find the opposite answer with you that is the results are with quotes.

Actually it's very easy to remove it automatically, just remove the param "separators=(',', ':')".

For me, just adding this param is Okay.